# Azure Active Directory /.auth/refresh The refresh request issued by failed because no refresh tokens were found in the token store

Tags: cordova, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have a Cordova app which is authenticating successfully with Azure Active Directory using the JS client SDK.  I have made the changes to my Azure Web Site per the instructions in CGillum's post.  This successfully gives me a token that I can use with Microsoft Graph and it returns a refresh token when calling `/.auth/me`.

However, when I try to call `/.auth/refresh`, I am getting a **403** error and the logs show the following.

```
2017-02-01T16:00:54  PID[8648] Warning     The refresh request issued
by sid... failed because no refresh tokens were found in the token
store. 
2017-02-01T16:00:54  PID[8648] Information Sending response: 403.80 Forbidden
```

I have the token store turned on in my Azure Web Sites settings.  I also noticed that if I call `/.auth/me`, it doesn't return the refresh token any more.  That may be intended behavior because I know with some providers it will only give you a refresh token once (not sure with AAD though).

```
  public getAccessTokenFromRefreshTokenFromAppService(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
  let apiUrl = Resources.azureMobileClientUrl + '/.auth/refresh';
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', this.azureService.mobileServiceClient.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
  return this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Get Refresh Token - ', data);
      let token = data.authenticationToken;

      resolve(data);
    },
    error => {
      reject(error);
    },
    () => {
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Are you using the Mobile Apps JS SDK, or are you using ADAL.JS? If the latter, this is expected - the client would be the one getting the tokens, and therefore is responsible for refresh. Any additional detail, like a code snippet for your login and refresh actions, would help.

Comment: I'm using the Mobile Apps JS SDK.  I added the code snippet to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your requirement, you want to enable refresh token in Azure Web Apps/ Mobile Apps as mentioned at http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/ by cgillum.

As what he mentioned, if you plan to enable this functionality by AAD IDP, we need several additional configurations on our App Services. And you can refer to http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/ for more details.

Generally speaking, there are 2 steps to enable it:

1. Generate a key in your AAD application, and consent two permissions of **Windows Azure Active Directory**: `Read directory data`& `Read directory data`:
   [image]
2. Update App Service Auth Configuration via REST API

   - set the key your generated above in the Authentication / Authorization section of your App Service.
     [image]
   - Step into Azure Resource Explorer
     [image]
     Set `additionalLoginParams` to `["response_type=code id_token", "resource=https://graph.windows.net"]`
     [image]

Comment: These are the steps I followed.  I have set the permissions and configured it to work with the Microsoft Graph.  When I call /.auth/me I can get an access token and a refresh token is returned.  However, when I call the /.auth/refresh endpoint, that is when it is saying that there is no tokens in the store.